# Нужно создать множество из значений подстрок в значениях признака

Tags: python, строки, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Есть признак в DataFrame, значения у которого - строка, содержащая разное число подстрок через запятую: `df.head` - ниже:

```
0              ['European', 'French', 'International']
1                                                  NaN
2    ['Japanese', 'Sushi', 'Asian', 'Grill', 'Veget...
3                                                  NaN
4    ['German', 'Central European', 'Vegetarian Fri...
Name: Cuisine Style, dtype: object
```

И так далее, до 11 подстрок в каждой.

Как извлечь вручную каждое значение каждого элемента строки в нужном виде?

Нашла, а в цикл или функцию, чтобы все прогнать и загнать в множество, никак не получается.

```
    df['Cuisine Style']= df['Cuisine Style'].apply(lambda s: 
s.replace('[','') if isinstance(s, str) else s)
df['Cuisine Style']= df['Cuisine Style'].apply(lambda s: s.replace(']','') 
if isinstance(s, str) else s)
cuisine_set = set()
for string in df['Cuisine Style']:
    cui_list=df['Cuisine Style'][string].split(',')
    for cuisine in cui_list:
        cuisine=cuisine[1:-1]
        if cuisine in cuisine_set:
            continue
        else:
            cuisine_set.add(cuisine)
cuisine_set
```

Comment: Приведите ваш код, мы поправим/дополним

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: код добавила, ссылка на файл https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eOwyjsb8dJTMlG8BkT5A5ME9k5KBiM1t/view?usp=sharing, потому что не выходит воспроизвести df

Comment: Как ни крутил эту фразу: _Нашла, а в цикл или функцию, чтобы все прогнать и загнать в множество_, так и не понял, что вы имели ввиду. Поправте пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
from yaml import safe_load   #   pip install pyyaml

res = df["Cuisine_Style"].apply(safe_load).to_list()
```

---

результат:

```
In [9]: res
Out[9]: [['European', 'French'], ['Italian']]
```

---

Исходный фрейм:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
            Cuisine_Style
0  ['European', 'French']
1             ['Italian']
```

---

**UPD:**

> На выходе должно получится множество всех возможных из столбца
> значений {'European', 'French', 'Italian'.... }

```
In [128]: res = df["Cuisine Style"].dropna().map(safe_load).sum()

In [129]: len(res)
Out[129]: 95613

In [130]: len(set(res))
Out[130]: 125

In [131]: set(res)
Out[131]:
{'Afghani',
 'African',
 'Albanian',
 'American',
 'Arabic',
 'Argentinean',
 'Armenian',
 'Asian',
 'Australian',
 'Austrian',
 'Azerbaijani',
 'Balti',
 'Bangladeshi',
 'Bar',
 'Barbecue',
 'Belgian',
 'Brazilian',
 ...
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что не совсем точно могу указать исходник - такой Series не выходит создать. На выходе должно получится множество всех возможных из столбца значений {'European', 'French', 'Italian'.... }. Возможно, что оно и вообще вручную нужно делать или разбивать на отдельные функции.

Comment: @ЗинаидаСырочкина, как на счёт `df["Cuisine_Style"].apply(safe_load).sum()` ;)

Comment: У вас так красиво, у меня ругается на запятые между кухнями. или пишет, что float не имеет атрибута read. Думаю, что проблема в том, что значения не воспринимаются списками, а воспринимаются строкой, потому я и пыталась разбить с помощью действий над строками, убирала скобки и разбивала на подстроки.

Comment: может быть, по ссылке получится посмотреть сам df https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eOwyjsb8dJTMlG8BkT5A5ME9k5KBiM1t/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @ЗинаидаСырочкина, нет, не дает - `You need access...` Вы пробовали решения из ответа? Что-то не получается?

Comment: Нет, не получается. Я тестила, пишет  ParserError: expected '<document start>', but found ','
  in "<unicode string>" или float have no attribute read
                               Переоткрыла доступ по ссылке, должно получиться